# Как прочитать определённые значения из файла?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Нужно загрузить из файла определённые значения: сам файл состоит из этого содержимого:

```
-Авторизация-
=====================
Ваш Токен: 0x9998509998332111
Ваш Логин: Tester
Ваш Пароль: testpassword123
```

---

Но этот метод просто читает всё с начальной строчки

```
public static void Load(string path, params TextBox[] contents)
{
  string result = Path.Combine(Dir, path);
  using (var sr = new StreamReader(result, Encoding.UTF8))
  {
     string[] line = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
     contents[0].Text = line[0];
     contents[1].Text = line[1];
     contents[2].Text = line[2];
  }
}
```

---

В каждый из текстбоксом нужно применить отдельные значения:

```
1 - 0x9998509998332111
2 - Tester
3 - testpassword123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Загружаем файл (или получаем эти данные от куда надо):

  ```
  File.ReadAllLines("Test.txt")
  ```
- Берем из полученного массива строк только те, что содержат `:`:

  ```
  .Where(x => x.Contains(':'))
  ```
- Преобразуем в разбитый массив по указанному символу:

  ```
  .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
  ```
- Формируем словарь:

  ```
  .ToDictionary(k => k[0], v => v[1])
  ```

Весь код и пример использования:

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines("Test.txt")
    .Where(x => x.Contains(':'))
    .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
    .ToDictionary(k => k[0], v => v[1]);

var pass = result["Ваш Пароль"]; // testpassword123
```

---

Если хотите убрать "Ваш", то либо разбивайте по пробелу, либо делайте такое:

```
private static string FormateKey(string value)
{
    var values = new[] { "Токен", "Логин", "Пароль" };
    return values.FirstOrDefault(x => value.Contains(x));
}
```

и

```
.ToDictionary(k => FormateKey(k[0]), v => v[1]);
```

---

Если словарь вовсе не нужен, то:

```
.Select(x => x.Split(':'))
.ToDictionary(k => FormateKey(k[0]), v => v[1]);
```

заменяем на

```
.Select(x => x.Split(':').Last());
```

Это даст вам массив лишь необходимых значений.